# How would i send a push notification from tizen to android?

Tags: android, notifications, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I want to send a notification to an android app based on some changes in the watch accelerometer, the watch is gear 2 running tizen. I can send notifications from android to the watch but not vice versa. How would I proceed with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Producer-Consumer (Companion) App using Accessory SDK. One for Android and one for Tizen gear. Add listeners in Tizen app and send data to android app when there is change in accelerometer reading.

You can refer [Accessory SDK](http://developer.samsung.com/galaxy#accessory) for more developing conpanion apps.